# TypeError: expect(...).toEqual is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am following Dan Abramov's tutorial on Redux. (https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread)

In lesson's 9 he introduces testing and using `expect` and `.toEqual()`

This is my code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var freeze = require('deep-freeze-node');

const testToggleTodo = () => {
    const todoBefore = {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Learn Redux',
        completed: false
    };

    const todoAfter = {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Learn Redux',
        completed: true
    };

    expect(
        toggleTodo(todoBefore)
        ).toEqual(todoAfter)
}

testToggleTodo();
console.log('All tests passed.')
```

and I keep getting an error:

```
.../react_redux/src/a.js:24
        ).toEqual(todoAfter)
          ^

TypeError: expect(...).toEqual is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? I am copying his code verbatim, but it leads to errors.

Comment: The source of truth is always in the official documentation not in someone's blog: http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect

Answer (score 10):

For me, my `.toEqual` was following the wrong brackets. Make sure it's `expect(...).toEqual(..)`, and not `expect(...(...).toEqual(...))`

Answer (score 3):

in my case to make it work I done following:

```
1. npm install --save expect                                install package from npm
2. import expect from 'expect';                             import lib in file
3. expect(toggleTodo(stateBefore, action)).toEqual(stateAfter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the provided syntax was ever correct for the `chai` library. (I would assume they are using some other assertion library)

The way the equality should be checked with its `expect` function is

```
expect(toggleTodo(todoBefore)).to.equal(todoAfter);
```

References:

- http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal

Comment: I am trying to understand why his code works and mine doesn't, not necessarily modify the code to make it work.

Comment: @MorganAllen provide their complete code including imports. From the video it's not obvious what is `expect`.

Comment: @MorganAllen how do you know it's `chai` then?

Comment: I don't, and I think that's the problem. Found this: https://github.com/robinjmurphy/getting-started-with-redux/commit/b4ed816062f33415161d40ffd751d38c6c3a883e looks like he is using `import expect from 'expect'`

Comment: @MorganAllen so you've found the reason then :-)

Answer (score 0):

was using the wrong package

shouldn't use chai,

import expect from 'expect'